# display json coming from server java Map onto jqgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

Any suggestion onto how to display the following json onto jqgrid?  The issue here is that this is coming from server and I cannot modify server side code.

field 123, 9785 and 9785 are dynamic which means they change and not static everytime. So how would I do this using colModel or beforeProcessing in jqgrid?

how do I get the sub data under field 123 or 9737 etc?

any code snippet would help me out

Thanks!

```
{
        "myJavaMap": {
            "123": {
                "a": "9716",
                "b": 1222652985000,
                "c": null,
                "d": null,
                "e": 6,
                "f": 1,
                "g": 0,
                "h": 0,
                "1": "OFFLINE"
            },
            "9737": {
                "a": "9737",
                "b": 1222652985000,
                "c": null,
                "d": null,
                "e": 6,
                "f": 1,
                "g": 0,
                "h": 0,
                "i": "OFFLINE"
            },
            "9785": {
                "a": "9785",
                "b": 1222652985000,
                "c": null,
                "d": null,
                "e": 6,
                "f": 1,
                "g": 0,
                "h": 0,
                "i": "OFFLINE"
            }
        },
        "xyz": 99
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, but the jqGrid plugin gives you the root option which allows you to establish what the root of your JSON element is. The document defines the root as `where our data begins and all other loops begin from this element.`

```
$("#yourGrid").jqGrid({

   jsonReader : { 
      root: "myJavaMap", 
      //rest of options
   },
});
```

The retrieving data section of the docs should help provide more info: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data&s[]=root

Comment: that did not help, 123 or 9737 etc are dynamic, how do I loop it out and display onto jqgrid

Comment: Ok you could try: `$.getJSON('yoururl').success( function(data){ var tableData = data.myJavaMap });` to get the data. Then you could use the `addJSONData()` function to load the data into a preset grid: `$('#grid').addJSONData( tableData );`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can solve your problem just using `jsonReader` with `root` defined as function. The `root` function should return **array** of items from `myJavaMap`. You should of cause use `loadonce: true` option because the server returns all data without implementing server side paging and sorting of data.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/onelazyguy.htm) demonstrates my suggestion and display the following grid

[image]

It uses as options

```
colModel: [
    { name: "a", key: true, template: intTemplate },
    { name: "b", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "c" },
    { name: "d" },
    { name: "e", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "f", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "g", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "h", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "i" }
],
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        var myRoot = obj.myJavaMap, arr = [], key;
        for (key in myRoot) {
            if (myRoot.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                arr.push(myRoot[key]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    },
    repeatitems: false
},
loadonce: true,
...
```

where `intTemplate` I defined as

```
var intTemplate = {formatter: "integer", align: "right", sorttype: "integer",
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"]
        }};
```

Comment: Thank Oleg, you are the best! I did not use your implementation but rather change the server side instead.